# JSON parse error in iOS

Tags: ios, json, web-services, soap

I am trying to parse json response(which I get from result tag of a SOAP webservice response) as shown in pictures with following lines.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                         "<soap:Body>"
                         "<GetPhotoSession xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                         "<UserID>%@</UserID>"
                         "<photoSessionID>%@</photoSessionID>"
                         "</GetPhotoSession>"
                         "</soap:Body>"
                         "</soap:Envelope>",[HelperClass retrieveStringForKey:kUserID],self.currentSession.sessionID];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/GetPhotoSession" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection ) {
    self.webResponseData = [NSMutableData data];
}else {
    NSLog(@"Some error occurred in Connection");

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.webResponseData  setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.webResponseData  appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Some error in your Connection. Please try again.");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Received Bytes from server: %d", [self.webResponseData length]);
    NSString *myXMLResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [self.webResponseData bytes] length:[self.webResponseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",myXMLResponse);

    NSError *errorPointer;

    NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:myXMLResponse error:&errorPointer];

    NSString *jsonData = dict[@"soap:Envelope"][@"soap:Body"][@"GetPhotoSessionResponse"][@"GetPhotoSessionResult"][@"text"];

    NSData *data = [jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&errorPointer];

    NSLog(@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"Head"]);
}
```

But I am getting nil in "json" object. Here is the pastie link for JSON response http://pastie.org/9799331. Following is the description of error pointer.

Printing description of errorPointer:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7d0156a0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: Paste your JSON in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and check whether it's valid or not

Comment: JSONLint's result:  Parse error on line 5:
... "ImageBase64Data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Comment: Value of `ImageBase64Data` key is not a valid one, please check that, there will be newline character or " in between the value

Comment: @Rob No. It's the value of <GetPhotoSessionResult> tag which is a JSON response

Comment: I have gone through XML parsing and able to extract result. I got stuck on JSON parsing.

Comment: So it's a NSLog of `jsonData`? I'm trying to reconcile your code (which logs only `myXMLResponse` and `[json objectForKey:@"Head"]`) and your output.

Comment: Re-phrasing: ou are going to have to dive into the JSON text to find the JSON error. Another validator may provide more information on the JSON error.

Comment: @Rob yes nslog of jsonData prints string which is being shown in pictures.

Comment: OK. I was pursuing that because your reported error message ("JSON text did not start with array or object ...") is more consistent with non-JSON being passed to `NSJSONSerialization` rather than what Midhun/Zaph were pursing, namely that it is JSON, but is somehow malformed. Usually malformed JSON gives a more descriptive error. Your error suggests a more radical problem. I might suggest `NSLog` of `data` (which should appear in hex) so we can confirm no weird BOM or something like that. Just show us the start of it...

Comment: We really can not read the images well enough. Can you just copy/paste the data into the question?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your own web service or an existing one? If this is your own, are you sure your JSON is actually correct?

I believe the problem is here:

```
"ImageBase64Data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA .... blah blah ==
"
```

Note the key point here. That the closing double quote is on the next line. It should be

```
"ImageBase64Data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA .... blah blah =="
```

For future reference, it is far easier if you cut and paste the JSON payload text in your question versus showing an image.

So grabbing your data from here:

http://pastie.org/9799331#2,22,482

I have run it through this code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"badjson" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *jsonStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

//    jsonStr = [[jsonStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSData *jsonData = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"Error is %@", error);
NSLog(@"JSON is %@", json);
```

Note that I have one commented out line right now. When I do this, it fails. However the failure is different than what you listed above. I get.

> Error is Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control
>   character around character 120.) UserInfo=0x7f9519f71510
>   {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 120.}

If I uncomment out that line, then it works. Only showing a snippet of the output:

```
2014-12-26 12:03:35.020 Sample[49732:6379864] Error is (null)
2014-12-26 12:03:35.022 Sample[49732:6379864] JSON is {
     Head =     (
                 {
             ID = 1092;
             ImageBase64Data = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDACAWGBwYFCAcGhwkIiAmMFA0MCwsMGJGSjpQdGZ6eHJmcG6AkLicgIiuim5woNqirr7EztDOfJri8uDI8LjKzsb/
```

Your data is using an base64 output which uses newlines to delimit each encoded line. This is why you see at the end the text that looks like:

```
==
","ImageName"
```

You'll also notice the vast majority of lines in the Base64 look uniform .. because of this delimiting.

Strip out the newlines using this (you need to modify it for you code)

```
jsonStr = [[jsonStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

If that doesn't work, then you need to provide some more info:

-Is the output taken from Xcode console?
-Add in your code where the NSLog exists to get the output (if you don't have it, then please add one).
-Once you add the NSLog, provide that output

While it may seem like you've "already provided that info", there is obviously a gap in information. Else I would expect to see the same NSError output. So we're either missing steps, or maybe there is some other variance. For example, I'm running this in an iOS 8 simulator. Not that it should matter too much, but there is always a possibility that you're running on an older version of iOS that parses the JSON differently.

Comment: I agree that the JSON is not valid. And it's not just the new line at the very end of the base-64 string but rather throughout it every 72 or 80 characters. The new line characters definitely should not appear within the JSON strings (as Midhun MP pointed out). But I wonder if there isn't some more deeper problem, though, as the `NSJSONSerialization` error is not talking about unescaped control characters, but rather that it's not finding the JSON at all.

Comment: @Rob, you're right. The error would mention unescaped control characters. I also think you're right that ChampTaurus should show the NSData dump. Although a BOM would show up as characters in the console (I just tested this). It could be another non-printable character though.

Comment: @MobileBen I don't think that is the case. Please check my updated question with pastie link.

Comment: @ChampTaurus, what is your code to output the data you put in the pastie link? I am assuming that was a direct cut and paste from Xcode console? Can you update your code and show where you are `NSLog`'ing the JSON string? The problem here is that the Base 64 actually has a ton of newlines in it. It looks like the Base64 being output is being delimited by newlines. Please see my updated answer which details it a bit more.